# How can I replace this text in an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have an string that shows up "Banana"

I want to replace it with "Apple"

This is what I have

```
<span id="Fruit">Banana</span>
```

This is the script I'm using.

```
    var td1 = document.getElementById('Fruit');
    var text = document.createTextNode("Apple");
    td1.appendChild(text);
```

And this is what it shows up as.

BananaApple

```
    <span id="Fruit">
    "Banana"
    "Apple"
    </span>
```

How can I get rid of Banana and just replace it with Apple?

```
<span id="Fruit">Apple</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just update the innerHTML: http://jsfiddle.net/SNtmL/

```
document.getElementById('Fruit').innerHTML = "Apple";
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a single `textNode`:

```
var td1 = document.getElementById('Fruit'),
    text = document.createTextNode("Apple");
td1.replaceChild(text,td1.firstChild);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/anuDg/).

Or:

```
var td1 = document.getElementById('Fruit');
td1.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Apple';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/anuDg/1/).

Or:

```
var td1 = document.getElementById('Fruit'),
    text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
td1[text] = 'Apple';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/anuDg/2/).

References:

- [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).
- [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild).

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a new text node, you want to alter the existing one.

A quick and dirty solution is:

```
document.getElementById("Fruit").innerHTML = "Apple";
```

Comment: Not sure why it's not showing any edits, however that isin't your original answer and you copied smerny's answer...

Comment: @plalx: First of all, edits within the first five minutes by the same author are automatically merged. Second, that's right, this isn't my "original" answer, however, I did not copy anything from anyone. I merely reread the question and decided that this was the best answer. Rather than what I had beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

For a more efficient way in removing all nodes from within the parent, you can always use the `while()` conditional:

```
var td1 = document.getElementById("Fruit"), text = document.createTextNode("Apple");
while(td1.hasChildNodes()) {
    td1.removeChild(td1.firstChild);
}
td1.appendChild(text);
```